# Returning a Spring Model in a @ModelAttribute annotated method

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, modelattribute

Can I use a Spring model as a model in a method annotated with the @ModelAttribute?  I get an error saying it can't find the attribute in the model.

Here is the method where I add my object to the model:

```
@ModelAttribute("survivor")
public Model getSurvivors(Model m) {
    m.addAttribute("decedent", new Decedent());

    return m;
}
```

Here is the render method. It prints 'model contains decedent=true'

```
@RenderMapping(params="render=survivors")
public String showSurvivors(Model model, RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws Exception {
    logger.info("in showSurvivors");
    logger.debug("model contains decedent={}, mode.containsAttribute("decedent");
    return "survivors";
}
```

Here is the jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="survivor" action="${submitAction}">
<form:input path="decedent.firstName" />
```

Error:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag
>   Invalid property 'decedent' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap]: Bean
>   property 'decedent' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:
>   Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the
>   setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in essence doing this:

```
model.addAttribute("survivor", model);
```

The issue that you are seeing in the `form:input` is that it is expecting a getter `decedent` on model which does not exist. The fix could be to use another wrapper type on top of a normal Map:

```
public class MyCommand{
    private Map<String, Decedent> decedents;
...getters and setters.
}
```

..

```
model.addAttribute("survivor", ..); //Add MyCommand type..
```

..

```
<form:form commandName="survivor" action="${submitAction}">
<form:input path="decedents['decedent']" />
```

Comment: Excellent, the first line above says it all.